# CUDA error in matlab (all CUDA-capable devices are busy)

Tags: matlab, cuda

- I want to use CUDA7.5 in matlab 2016a (or matlab 2014), for example, I can set gpu in matlab by `gpuDevice(gpu_id)` At the begining, this always works.
- But after i have run some *.m files which are reletive with cuda, i always get the following error when i run `gpuDevice(gpu_id)` again.

  > **An unexpected error occurred during CUDA execution. The CUDA error was:
  >   all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable**
- I have tried to restart the matlab and my computer, but the error is still here. Does anyone know why this will happen? And how can i fix this error?
- Thanks so much!
- In addition, when I run `gpuDevice` in the commond line, I have obtained the following information

> ```
>              Name: 'GeForce GTX 960'
>              Index: 1
>  ComputeCapability: '5.2'
>     SupportsDouble: 1
>      DriverVersion: 7.5000
>     ToolkitVersion: 7.5000
> MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
>   MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
> MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
>        MaxGridSize: [2.1475e+09 65535 65535]
>          SIMDWidth: 32
>        TotalMemory: 4.2950e+09
>    AvailableMemory: 3.4769e+09    
>  MultiprocessorCount: 8
>       ClockRateKHz: 1291000
>        ComputeMode: 'Default'   GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1 KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
>   CanMapHostMemory: 1
>    DeviceSupported: 1
>     DeviceSelected: 1
> ```

Comment: When I use CUDA mex files in MATLAB, once the mex files have "taken" the GPU, then I ca not use any of the MATLAB GPU functions. Somehow MATLAB allocates the GPU to the mex files and doesn't let me use them even if I released them in CUDA code. No idea why, but yeah, the only option I can use is restarting MATLAB

Comment: Even i have restarted my computer and matlab, the error is still there. So sad!

Comment: That also happens to me when I have single GPU and its being used by the OS for graphics. No idea how to solve it sorry.

Answer (score 1):

After using the GPU, you should [reset the gpu](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/reset.html) with `reset` which will

```
dev = gpuDevice(gpu_id);

% Do lots of stuff
reset(dev)
```

Or you could release the device using empty (`[]`) inputs

```
gpuDevice([])
```

Comment: Just now, I have restart my computer and matlab, then I have typed `gpu_id = 1;gpuDevice(gpu_id);`, 
but I still obtain the same error. Then I have typed
`
dev = gpuDevice(gpu_id);
% Do lots of stuff
reset(dev)`;
`
the error is sitll there.
Also, i have typed `gpuDevice([])`, the error is also there. 

The error information is
An unexpected error occurred during CUDA execution. The CUDA error was:
all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable

Comment: Just now, I have restart my computer and matlab, then I have typed `gpu_id = 1;gpuDevice(gpu_id);`, 
but I still obtain the same error. Then I have typed
` dev = gpuDevice(gpu_id); reset(dev)`,the error is sitll there.
Also, i have typed `gpuDevice([])`, the error is also there. 

The error information is: 

An unexpected error occurred during CUDA execution. The CUDA error was:
all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable

Do you know how to solve this problem? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same error with you. I run matlab in linux, after I delete ~/.matlab, and then restart matlab, the error just goes.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today and it's very weird because I have run the same program before without any problem. I checked gpu usage and it turned out someone was running python on gpu0 and taken all memory. I did gpu device selection in matlab but some toolkits may still use gpu0 as default.
And the python program is done, the problem just goes.